# Надо спарсить сайт, не могу найти элемент

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Мне надо написать парсер, который будет собирать все сообщения из чата Kick и предоставлять их мне. Я начал реализовывать этот код на python с помощью библиотекой selenium. На данный момент написал код что бы просто открывался хромдвайвер и в нём был чат кика, но не могу понять как мне собрать сообщения так-как не за что зацепиться.

```
from sys import executable
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

if use_proxy:
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=193.32.155.4:8000')

if user_agent:
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        
        
s = Service(
    executable_path='chromdriver/chromedriver.exe'
)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service= s,
    options=chrome_options
)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    'source': '''
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_JSON;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Object;
        delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Proxy;
'''
})

return driver


def main():
try:
    driver = get_chromedriver(
        use_proxy=False,
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    )
    driver.get('https://kick.com/islandboys')
         
    time.sleep(1000)
    
except Exception as _ex:
    print(_ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Можно искать по классу `mt-0.5` можно по `chat-entry`